# BigQuery - Union All tables in a dataset

Tags: google-bigquery, union-all

I have a dataset in BigQuery where I upload a new table every 2 days. All tables are the same.

Want to write and schedule a query than Union all tables, including when a newone is uploaded to the dataset.

Using the below one and is working, however every time I add a new table I need to manually include it in the query. Looking for an option where the query is querying all tables in the dataset.

````
(Select * from PnL.kapitani as cl WHERE cl.billing_date is not null)
Union ALL (Select * from PnL.One_Time WHERE billing_date is not null)
Union ALL (Select * from PnL.DSP WHERE billing_date is not null)
Union ALL (Select * from PnL.strypes WHERE billing_date is not null)
Union ALL (Select * from PnL.Cloud_Office WHERE billing_date is not null))```
````

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> All tables are the same.
> Looking for an option where the query is querying all tables in the dataset.

You can use [`Wildcard tables`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference) feature of BigQuery

So, you query can look simply like below

```
Select * from PnL.* WHERE billing_date is not null
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it good enough. Need to to get a result of all the information from within the tables.

Comment: this is still not clear what exactly your expected output.please update your question with more details!